# Function that calls function with out parameter leads to error

Tags: postgresql

I'm new at PostgreSQL so this is probably a dumb question but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere. So any help is appreciated.

I have a function (func_main) that calls another function (func_out) that has some OUT parameters. I always get an error that the function cannot be found. If I call a function that does not have OUT parameters (func_no_out) it works fine.

Below is the code for func_out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_out (argin integer, argout1 OUT integer, argout2 OUT integer) AS $body$
BEGIN
    argout1 := argin;
    argout2 := 2 * argin;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

The code for func_no_out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_no_out (argin integer) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
DECLARE
    argout1 integer;
    argout2 integer;
BEGIN
    argout1 := argin;
    argout2 := 2 * argin;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

And finally the main function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_main (argin integer) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
DECLARE
    dummy1 integer;
    dummy2 integer;
BEGIN
    --PERFORM func_out(argin, dummy1, dummy2);
    PERFORM func_no_out(argin);
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

Manually calling func_out works fine.

```
=> select * from func_out(5);
 argout1 | argout2
---------+---------
       5 |      10
(1 row)
```

When calling func_out from func_main the error I get is:

```
=> select * from func_main(6);
ERROR:  function func_out(integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT func_out(argin, dummy1, dummy2)
```

So what am I doing wrong in func_main?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Henry

Answer (score 0):

Ughh.. I should have googled a bit more.

OUT parameters should not be in the PERFORM arguments. So it should be:

```
PERFORM func_out(argin);
```

And if I do want the output parameters, I need to use:

```
SELECT * FROM func_out(argin) INTO dummy1, dummy2;
```